# Is the WCF Web.API safe for production applications?

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-web-api

The WCF Web.API hasn't been incorporated into the .NET Framework as of the date of this post. Is it safe to use this library in production code or is it's only usefulness for testing at the moment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using it in production.

Albeit it is not allowed at the moment to use it in production at your customers site.

But your customer can get the dependencies using Nuget...

And btw: Web API will be out of band release like ASP.NET MVC is.

Answer (score 3):

While I personally have not implemented a production application with WCF web API, I know several people who have.  I have not heard them report any issues that would cause me to question it's production readiness.  That being said, WCF Web API is an open source project, so you can browse the code yourself to get a feeling for how sound the code is.

Comment: I know the api is dependable, my problem is licensing. I can't use it at work unless its rc.

Comment: Ha, well, I don't think anyone on satckoverflow can help you with that problem :)